# Fill down multiple columns in HTML file with AWK

Tags: awk, command-line, html

using AWK I am trying to fill down a HTML table (rows/columns) based on the previous value. Similar to excel.

eg:

```
table
user$ csv2html.awk table.csv


        rowing | fast | good
               | fast | good
        swim   |      | 
               |      | slow
               |      | increase
               | late | 
        golf   | red  | bad
```

I want this html table to then become the following:

```
table
        rowing | fast | good
        rowing | fast | good
        swim   | fast | good
        swim   | fast | slow
        swim   | fast | increase
        swim   | late | increase
        golf   | red  | bad
```

The table can have any number of columns/rows and the values can vary across many different words. I am simply trying to understand how to parse the html and then fill down the value that I find in each column/row.

Output must be to a new html file that keeps formatting.

UPDATE:

```
<html><body><table>
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th>Column2</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>rowing</td>
<td>fast</td>
<td>good</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>fast</td>
<td>good</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>swim</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table></body></html>
```

Comment: Please update your question to include a sample of the actual html (I’m assuming it’s using html table elements rather than just setting out in plain text?)

Comment: Please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add something like this to you `awk` script:

```c
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i==""){$i=last[i]}
    last[i]=$i
}
```

As you don't show us your script, you have to do that yourself.

Beginning with your resulting table, it could look like this:

```bsh
$ awk -F ' *\| *' '
    BEGIN{OFS="|"}
    {
      for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if($i==""){$i=last[i]}
        last[i]=$i
      }$1=$1
    }1' table
rowing|fast|good
rowing|fast|good
swim|fast|good
swim|fast|slow
swim|fast|increase
swim|late|increase
golf|red|bad
```

---

However! I would suppose you do the whole thing with a proper html parser instead of `awk`. I can recommend `python`'s [`beautifulsoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) module.

Or **even better**, use a proper data analysis tool,
e.g. `pandas`, which provides exactly this functionality with its [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) method:

> `ffill`: propagate last valid observation forward to next valid

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd
with open('file.html') as f:
    html = f.read()
    df = pd.read_html(html)[0]
    df = df.ffill()
    df.head()
```

Output:

```
   Column1 Column2 Column3
0  rowing    fast    good
1  rowing    fast    good
2    swim    fast    good
```

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46068609/pandas-fill-empty-trailing-values-with-last-known-value).

Answer (score 1):

While @pLumo has nailed it, the multichar regex `FS` is not playing nicely with my version of `gawk` (5.1.0) for some reason so an alternate to clean up the whitespace ....

```
awk -F'\|' 'BEGIN{OFS="<\\td>\n<td>"; ORS="<\\td>\n<\\tr>\n"}
   {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "", $i); $i=(!$i)?last[i]:$i; last[i]=$i
   } printf "<tr>\n<td>"}1' file

<tr>
<td>rowing<\td>
<td>fast<\td>
<td>good<\td>
<\tr>
<tr>
<td>rowing<\td>
<td>fast<\td>
<td>good<\td>
<\tr>
<tr>
<td>swim<\td>
<td>fast<\td>
<td>good<\td>
<\tr>
<tr>
<td>swim<\td>
<td>fast<\td>
<td>slow<\td>
<\tr>
<tr>
<td>swim<\td>
<td>fast<\td>
<td>increase<\td>
<\tr>
<tr>
<td>swim<\td>
<td>late<\td>
<td>increase<\td>
<\tr>
<tr>
<td>golf<\td>
<td>red<\td>
<td>bad<\td>
<\tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd be simpler and more robust to fill the CSV and then generate HTML than generate HTML first and then fill the HTML but...

```
$ awk -F'</?td>' 'NF>1{$0=($2=="" ? "<td>"prev"</td>" : $0); prev=$2} 1' file
<html><body><table>
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th>Column2</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>rowing</td>
<td>fast</td>
<td>good</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>good</td>
<td>fast</td>
<td>good</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>swim</td>
<td>swim</td>
<td>swim</td>
</tr>
</table></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-off task that doesn't need to be scripted, you can import an HTML table into some spreadsheet programs like LibreOffice Calc, use their fill-down feature and then save it back to HTML.